# SQL: Is there a way to get the average number of characters for a field?

Tags: sql

Is there a simple sql query that can help me to determine the average number of characters that a (text) database field has?

For instance my field is called "message".  Ideally I would love to do something like this...

```
select average(characterlength(message)) from mydatabasetable
```

is this even possible through sql?

Thanks!

Comment: which RDBMS? Oracle, Sybase, MySQL, SQL Server?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit**

*Original bad phrasing:*  In SQL Server, LEN is for varchar fields.  For Text fields, try [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)

*Correction because @gbn is right:*  LEN will not work with Text or NText datatypes.  For TEXT, try Datalength.

**End Edit**

```
SELECT AVG(DATALENGTH(yourtextfield)) AS TEXTFieldSize
```

**Edit - added**

The above is for the TEXT datatype. For NTEXT, divide by 2.

Comment: LEN gives you characters trimmed, DATALENGTH gives you bytes untrimmed. Whether varchar or nvarchar affects results of course, but "LEN is for varchar fields" is not actually correct

Comment: -1 for misleading now it is accepted: Klaus Byskov Hoffmann's answer is correct

Comment: @gbn, then please explain this error: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of len function. It comes up with the text data type as well.  The question specifically asked about the Text data type, and this error was pointed out in a comment on @dmcnelis's answer.

Comment: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function.

Comment: Also, this is well documented in several places. All you have to do is google "SQL Server LEN Text datatype". For example, here: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1188  You should check your facts before voting down.

Comment: Not to mention that I actually bothered to take the time to TEST both statements before posting an answer.

Comment: Except text and ntext are deprecated since SQL Server 2005. It  is one of the *few* functions that worked with text and ntext. LEN works with nvarchar(max). Your answer is even more wrong now. Did you check books on line on MSDN for what MS says? That article we'd dated when written-DTS was deprecated too. So, Len and datalength are independent of datatype for most recent 3 versions of SQL Server

Comment: @gbn. Yes, it does. But look at the question. He specified (text). You are 100% correct for varchar(max) and nvarchar(max)but wrong for the actual question asked. Not that it matters. I'm just annoyed about other things, so this little thing set me off. Sorry to be such a baby about it.

Comment: Your answer is correct for the datatype - I object to the "Len is for varchar" bit

Comment: You are right. That was a stupid way for me to word it. I was trying to answer before someone else did and did not pay enogh attention to how I worded it. I corrected my answer, giving credit where credit is due. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 14):

```
select avg(length(fieldname)) from table
```

Though the answer could potentially differ depending on your RDBMS.

Comment: "length" is Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function....  (length was invalid, so I replaced it with "len")

Comment: length is the postgresql version

Answer (score 7):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT AVG(CHAR_LENGTH(<column>)) AS avgLength FROM <table>
```

Retrieved from:

```
http://forums.devshed.com/database-management-46/average-length-field-38905.html
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select avg(length(textfield)) from mytable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. In SqlServer for example it would be:

```
SELECT AVG(LEN(Name)) FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(len(theTextColumn)) / count(*) from theTable;
```